# Maps Navigation Intent for Amazon Kindle Devices

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, kindle

I tried finding this via google search and searching through stackoverflow. I would think this would be a simple thing if it exists...

Is there a way to create an Intent on Amazon devices to start navigation with their maps app?

Something like the following (as it works on **most** Android devices)

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + latitude + ","
                + longitude)));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: That `Intent` does not work "on Android". It only works on Android devices that happen to support that `Uri` structure in some `ACTION_VIEW` activity. At the moment, that perhaps includes the Google Maps app. However, not only can Google get rid of support for this (as it is undocumented and unsupported), no other maps app has to support it. Not only do you have a problem with devices that lack Google Maps outright (e.g., Kindle Fire series), but also any device on which the user has disabled Google Maps, perhaps choosing a different map application instead.

Comment: The user base for this particular app understands that Google Maps, and Google Play Services in general, is a requirement for this particular function (the function being navigation to a destination). I apologize if I was unclear in that. I'm merely attempting to add support for Amazon devices. I have since, however, found a solution that works for me. Either way, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering, the below code will work for launching the default Amazon maps app, without going directly into navigation. Tested on Kindle Fire HD 7 running FireOS 4.5.2

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude)));
```

where latitude and longitude are of type String.